# Android MutableLiveData.value = getNewValue() does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelivedata

Why it's not possible to directly set the mutableLiveData.value when using a suspend function? See following code:

```
private val _clubs: MutableLiveData<List<ClubEntity>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<ClubEntity>>().also {
        fetchClubListFromRepository()
    }
}

private fun fetchClubListFromRepository() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // This does NOT work, no error but the UI does not update.
            // _clubs.value = clubsRepository.getAllClubs()
            // This works, the UI updates.
            var clubsList = clubsRepository.getAllClubs()
            _clubs.value = clubsList
        }
}

suspend fun getAllClubs(): List<ClubEntity> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ClubsApi.RETROFIT_SERVICE.getClubs()
    }
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/mobilekosmos/Soccer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mobilekosmos/android/clubs/ui/model/ClubsViewModel.kt#L91)

Comment: At first glance both look fine and exactly equivalent. By "does not work", what do you mean happens? Compile error or nothing happens at runtime, or...?

Comment: With "does not work" I mean that the UI does not change, it changes with the second approach, no error whatsoever.

Comment: Initially it's null that's why liveData not updated
clubsRepository.getAllClubs()?.let{
_clubs.value =it
}

Comment: @GobuCSG it's not null.

Comment: may be It's asynchronous call

Comment: Have you tried to remove `.also` and just `private val _clubs: MutableLiveData<List<ClubEntity>> by lazy { fetchClubListFromRepository() }` ? After modifying method of course.

Comment: @SkypeDogg have you tried it? That wouldn't compile.

Comment: I think the root problem is this `suspend fun getClubs(): List<ClubEntity>` it should be `suspend fun getClubs(): Response<List<ClubEntity>>`

Comment: @cutiko That's not the root problem, it may be the solution though. I think the problem is a timing issue, when fetchClubListFromRepository is called it seems that _clubs is still not initialized so fetchClubListFromRepository() is actually called again. With the 2nd approach background work is running which gives the runtime time to complete the initialization, at least that's how I understand it currently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a timing issue, when fetchClubListFromRepository is called it seems that _clubs is still not initialized so fetchClubListFromRepository() is actually called again. With the 2nd approach background work is running which gives the runtime time to complete the initialization, at least that's how I understand it currently.